# Is it correct to express $\lim \limits_{\eta\to\infty}f(\eta)$ as $f(\infty)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, notation

Hi I have a really basic question that unclear to me for long long time...

Is it correct to express $\lim \limits_{\eta\to\infty}f(\eta)$
as $f(\infty)$?

I always use the former, however I saw the latter used very often but not sure they are the same thing.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: It depends on the context. Sometimes $\infty$ is an actual object and if it happens to be in the domain of $f$, then $f(\infty)$ is a valid entity in its own right and it can be different from $\lim \limits_{\eta\to\infty}\left(f(\eta)\right)$. But if $\infty$ isn't an actual object, like in Calculus, then $f(\infty)$ is defined as the limit of $f$ at $\infty$ and this is acceptable.

Comment: I am considering the context of calculus, $f(\infty)$ denotes limit of $f$ at infinity? And $\lim_{\eta\to\infty}f(\eta)$ denotes the limit of $f$ as $\eta$ tends to infinity?

Comment: Different words for the same thing, what I meant was that $f(\infty):=\lim \limits_{\eta\to\infty}\left(f(\eta)\right)$ in this context.

Comment: $f(\infty)$ doesn't mean anything, until it's defined. If someone writes, "I will use $f(\infty)$ to mean $\lim_{\eta\to\infty}f(\eta)$," then it's OK for her to use $f(\infty)$ thereafter. Otherwise, not.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson. So it is always safer to write $\lim_{\eta\to\infty}f(\eta)$?

Comment: Writing $f(\infty)$ is perfectly safe, so long as you make it clear what you mean by that notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to \infty } f(\eta ) $ exists then $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to \infty } f(\eta ) $ is either finite or infinite.

If $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to \infty } f(\eta ) $ is finite then $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to \infty } f(\eta )=l $ for some $ l\in \mathbb{R} $.

Then $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to \infty } f(\eta )=l $ means for any $ \epsilon >0 $, there exists $ a_{\epsilon}\in \mathbb{R} $ such that for each $ \eta >a_{\epsilon} $, $ \vert f(\eta )-l\vert <\epsilon $.

If $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to \infty } f(\eta ) $ is infinite then either $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to \infty } f(\eta )=\infty $ or $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to \infty } f(\eta )=-\infty $.

$ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to \infty } f(\eta )=\infty $ means for any $ M>0 $, there exists $ a_{M}\in \mathbb{R} $ such that for each $ \eta >a_{M} $, $ f(\eta )>M $.

Similarly $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to \infty } f(\eta )=-\infty $ means for any $ M>0 $, there exists $ a_{M}\in \mathbb{R} $ such that for each $ \eta >a_{M} $, $ f(\eta )<-M $.

But $ f(\infty ) $ does not mean anything. Therefore you can't express $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to \infty } f(\eta ) $ as $ f(\infty ) $.

Comment: I am not so sure that one can categorically deny meaning to $f(\infty)$. Just maybe the OP is in a class where real analysis is introduced with the help of the [extended real line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). And from continuity considerations the times when $f(\infty)$ is already defined may be more problematic when it comes to the use of the notation $f(\infty)$.